# Monotouch: OpenFlowSharp, ViewDidLoad method not called

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios

I'm using OpenFlowSharp by Miguel De Icaza. I'm creating some test applications...

My SampleController extends a UIViewController and implements IOpenFlowDataSource...

```
SampleController : UIViewController, IOpenFlowDataSource
```

I have also created a custom navigation controller MyNavigationController that extends UINavigationController. It adds only some functionalities to the basic extended controller.
I don't override any methods provided the UINavigationController.

```
MyNavigationController : UINavigationController
```

The problem is that when I push a SampleController instance in MyNavigationController, ViewDidLoad method on SampleController is not called. ViewDidAppear and ViewDidDisappear are called normally.

Why? Any suggestions? Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm encountering the same problem. If I find one, I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are overriding a method, and you forgot to call the base implementation

Comment: Thank you Miguel. What do you mean with "Perhaps you are overriding a method..."?

Comment: I've checked my overridden methods. I haven't forgotten any base implementation. Any other suggestions? Thank you.